# Triggering the second dropdown box to display values based on the values selected from first dropdown by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap dropdown boxes. One will display all country names from database based on the country selected by the user the other dropdown should select states when we click on the other dropdown.
I had made an ajax request to display country names when one dropdown is clicked. How to trigger the other dropdown based on the country selection?

```
$(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function(){
                 $.ajax({
                     type:'post',
                     url: 'Service.php',
                     dataType: 'json',//since you wait for json
                     data: {
                        'service': 'dropdown_country'
                    },
                     success: function(json){
                    //now when you received json, render options
                        $.each(json, function(i, option){
                            var rendered_option = '<li><a href="#">'+ option.country +'</a></li>';
                            $(rendered_option).appendTo('.dropdown-menu');
                        })
                        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
                            $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
                            $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
                        });
                    }
                })


            })
```

With the above thing, both the dropdowns are showing the country names when clicked. I need only first dropdown to show country names and other dropdown should call someother service when clicked to show state names based on the country selected in country dropdown. I am strucked in triggering the second dropdown box in ajax call. Please help.

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/tr1sSDm2

Comment: @HarnishKumar - i believe logically country dropdown should get filled via ajax only one time i.e. on page load. No need to repopulate it as and when somebody clicks on it. On the other hand; yes; state dropdown should get repopulated on each selection of country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*you are appending the content to class **.dropdown-menu** class can be same for many elements so to solve this use id with different name and then append your content*

example:

```
var rendered_option = '<li><a href="#">'+ option.country +'</a></li>';
                            $(rendered_option).appendTo('#dropdown-menu1');
                        })

var rendered_option = '<li><a href="#">'+ option.states +'</a></li>';
                            $(rendered_option).appendTo('#dropdown-menu2');
                        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Populate City Dropdown Using jQuery Ajax</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("select.country").change(function(){
    var selectedCountry = $(".country option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process-request.php",
        data: { country : selectedCountry } 
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#response").html(data);
    });
   });
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
 <form>
    <table>
       <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Country:</label>
            <select class="country">
                <option>Select</option>
                <option value="usa">United States</option>
                <option value="india">India</option>
                <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="response">
            <!--Response will be inserted here-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

The above code process and takes the request from  the php file

```
  <?php
       if(isset($_POST["country"])){
   // Capture selected country
   $country = $_POST["country"];

          // Define country and city array
            $countryArr = array(
                "usa" => array("New Yourk", "Los Angeles", "California"),
                "india" => array("Mumbai", "New Delhi", "Bangalore"),
                "uk" => array("London", "Manchester", "Liverpool")
            );

      // Display city dropdown based on country name
      if($country !== 'Select'){
       echo "<label>City:</label>";
       echo "<select>";
       foreach($countryArr[$country] as $value){
        echo "<option>". $value . "</option>";
       }
       echo "</select>";
      } 
       }
      ?>
```

Comment: keep the name which you are required  to test

Answer (score 0):

Got your Point. You have to only change html your return response dropdown .. Here is a e.g. http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/ . I have already use it also change it according to my requirement. Check it and enjoy the code.